# Read-only variable in Property Grid

Tags: c#, readonly, propertygrid

I want to create a variable (int) read-only in the Property Grid.

There is something I do not understand.

The variable is without set, why it still allows me to change the value (and fall when it fails to put the value into the variable)?

```
    private int _myVar= 1;

    public int MyVar
    {
        get { return _myVar; }
    }
```

Comment: Works for me. Displays `MyVar` as read-only.

Comment: With the code you show. Create a new project with a new empty class, paste that code into the class and see if it works there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [`ReadOnlyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.readonlyattribute.aspx):

```
private int _myVar= 1;

[ReadOnly(true)]
public int MyVar {
    get { return _myVar; }
}
```